# Javascript advanced loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = [
    [ 1234, 3456 ],
    [ 1324, 2345 ],
    [ 6355 ],
    [ 2234 ],
    [ 8345 ],
    [ 1234, 6355 ]
];
var i = arr.length;

while(i--){
    var current = arr[i];
    if(i == 0){
        break;
    }
    var before = arr[i-1];

    if(!before[1]) continue;

    var result = current[1] - before[1]
    console.log(result)
}
```

In the code above the child arrays which have value only in their 0 index will get eliminated as `if(!before[1]) continue;`.If you run this code result is `NaN` and then `-1111`  where `NaN` is because `arr[2][1]` is `undefined` while `before` is `2345`. And `-1111` is because `arr[1][1]` is `2345` and `arr[0][1]` is `3456` so substractiong before from current gives `-1111` .

As you can see array in the last index of `arr` bypassed while it has value in its 1st index `[1234, 6355]`. But in this case `current` could be aqual to `arr[5][1]` at first and then before equal to `arr[1][1]` first of all. I want exactly the same thing, to bypass arrays when they don't have any value in index zero only for `before` variable, while current keeps the value until it finds before.
Shortly in this example result should be:

6355 - 2345 = `4010 //arr[5][1] - arr[1][1]`

2345 - 3456 = `-1111 //arr[1][1] - arr[0][1]`

But currently it is only

`NaN //arr[2][1] - arr[1][1]
-1111 /arr[1][1] - arr[0][1]`

It should not eliminate any `current` when `before` is not found or any `before` when `current` is not found

Comment: I don't think you want to asign the variables in every loop....

Comment: _Array.prototype.map_ or _Array.prototype.forEach_ would be better to avoid it (depends on what you want to do)

Comment: Could you describe what do you want to achive ?

Comment: nAz I gave an example of what I want

Comment: @developer in the example above you describe your logic but not what it should do

Comment: Are you actually checking `result` in the loop? With the code in the example you will get only the result of the last round.

Comment: it should loop! I described what I want to achieve read the description

Comment: Teemu it is not important

Comment: So, I got the correct answer. Which means that question is understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you're trying to do decrementation with each sequential `arr[n][1]` excluding those `arr[n]`s, which have only one member.

You can do it this way:

```
var arr = [
        [1234, 3456],
        [1324, 2345],
        [6355],
        [2234],
        [8345],
        [1234, 6355]
    ],
    i = arr.length,
    result, firstOperand;

while (i--) {
    if (typeof firstOperand === 'undefined') { // No first operand 
        firstOperand = arr[i][1]; // Set the first operand
        continue;
    }
    if (arr[i].length < 2) {continue;} // No second operand, continue   
    result = firstOperand - arr[i][1];
    firstOperand = arr[i][1]; // Set a new first operand
    console.log(result);
}
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nm7avxp4/).

The trick is, that you store the first operand to a variable. Then check if it has a value. If not, assign a one and continue the loop. Then check if you've the second operand for decremention at the current index. If not found, continue the loop. Then when you've both operands, do the math, and assign a new `firstOperand`.

Notice, that `typeof` checking allows you to use also zero as a value. The code works also in a case when the length of some of the last members in `arr` is 1, or even when there are not valid members at all.

Answer (score 0):

[Update]
I think what you want is something like this:

```
var arr = [
[ 1234, 3456 ],
[ 1324, 2345 ],
[ 6355 ],
[ 2234 ],
[ 8345 ],
[ 1234, 6355 ]
];
var result; // Prepare result var
var before = 0; // Prepare "before" var
var current = 0; // Prepare "current" var
for (var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){ // Loop the length of Arr
    before = current; // store previous "current" as "before"
    if (arr[i][1] != null){ // Skip if no entry in array
        current = arr[i][1]; // Set "current" to array value
    }
    result = current-before; // Update result at end of each loop
}
console.log(result);
```

This gives you the result you're looking for (4010), and will skip the arrays where the value is not set..